# ROS message subfolder

Tags: ros, catkin, rosmessage, catkin-make-isolated, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I noticed that ROS does not correctly see message files in subfolders of the "msg" folder. The add_message_files command can take a DIRECTORY command which works partly:

```
add_message_files(
  DIRECTORY
  msg/subfolder1
  FILES
  testmessage.msg
)
```

Both `catkin_make_isolated` and `catkin build` run perfectly but after a `source devel/setup.bash`, the `rosmsg list` command does not show this testmessage. If I change the subfolder name to something different in the CMakeLists file, cmake complaints about the missing path. Hence, the folder path is recognized partly.

The only solution I found was to move all message files out of subfolders such they are directly placed at e.g., `msg/testmessage.msg`. Then, the `rosmsg list` command shows the message.

Is there another way to use subfolders for message definitions?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253386/ros-message-subfolder/) by [inspire](https://answers.ros.org/users/28884/inspire/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-01-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I confirmed this ([my code](https://goo.gl/8c6n15), which modifies `beginner_tutorial` to add a new msg file "Num5.msg" in a sub folder). Although msg artifact is generated, the new msg doesn't appear in `rosmsg list`. Used `catkin_make`. I can, however, use the new message Num5.msg in my ROS program. E.g. `rostopic pub Num5 beginner_tutorials/Num5 1` then subscribing to it can be done without problem.

More concrete commands and result:

```
roscd beginner_tutorials/msg
mkdir subfolder
(edit CMakeLists.txt to add subfolder to `add_message_files`)
echo "int64 num" > subfolder/Num2.msg
cd -
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
```

Then,

```
find ./devel -iname *Num2*    --> Generated.
rosmsg list|grep Num          --> Num2 not listed.
rostopic pub Num2 beginner_tutorials/Num2 1    --> Published.
rostopic echo /Num2    --> Printed as expected.
```

So maybe a specific issue with `rosmsg list`.

```
$ apt-cache policy ros-kinetic-catkin ros-kinetic-rosmsg   |grep Inst 
  Installed: 0.7.6-0xenial-20170217-212821-0800
  Installed: 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-194441-0800
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-18**:
[Reported on ros_comm](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1021) repo.